# CakePHP 2.0 naming MySQL aggregate functions in query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a complex query in my project that I am running in native SQL.

```
$r = $this->User->Project->query("
    SELECT
        Project.id,
        Project.name,
        Customer.name,
        (SELECT SUM(hours)
            FROM entries
            WHERE project_id = Project.id
                AND createdby = $id
                AND deleted = 0
                AND YEAR(entry_date) = YEAR(NOW())
                AND DAYOFYEAR(entry_date) = DAYOFYEAR(NOW())) as TodayHours,
        (SELECT SUM(hours)
            FROM entries
            WHERE project_id = Project.id
                AND createdby = $id
                AND deleted = 0
                AND YEAR(entry_date) = YEAR(NOW())
                AND WEEKOFYEAR(entry_date) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())) as WeekHours,
        (SELECT SUM(hours)
            FROM entries
            WHERE project_id = Project.id
                AND deleted = 0) as SpentHours,
        Project.budget_hours as TotalHours
    FROM projects as Project
        INNER JOIN users_projects UserProject on UserProject.project_id = Project.id
            AND UserProject.user_id = $id
        INNER JOIN customers Customer on Customer.id = Project.customer_id
    WHERE Project.deleted = 0
            AND Project.archived = 0
");
```

When the results comeback almost everything looks perfect. The only problem is that CakePHP throws my `SUM` columns off into their own grouping `[0]`. I would like to get them lumped in with `Project` if possible. Is there any way I can alias these fields so that will happen?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [name] => Some Project Name
                    [TotalHours] => 67.00
                )

            [Customer] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Some Customer Name
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [TodayHours] => 2.25
                    [WeekHours] => 27.25
                    [SpentHours] => 27.25
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to answer this so fast... I hope it helps other people who have the same question. Here is the solution. You basically have to setup empty virtual fields for your model and then alias the columns with MyModel__VirtualFieldName. After that it's perfect!

Side note that [@jose_zap](https://twitter.com/jose_zap) on Twitter is a CakePHP core developer and super, super helpful. Thanks again!

```
//Add the virtual fields for this specific case
$this->User->Project->virtualFields += array(
    'TodayHours' => 0,
    'WeekHours' => 0,
    'SpentHours' => 0
);

//Run the query
$projects = $this->User->Project->query("
    SELECT
        Project.id,
        Project.name,
        Customer.name,
        (SELECT SUM(hours)
            FROM entries
            WHERE project_id = Project.id
                AND createdby = $id
                AND deleted = 0
                AND YEAR(entry_date) = YEAR(NOW())
                AND DAYOFYEAR(entry_date) = DAYOFYEAR(NOW())) as Project__TodayHours,
        (SELECT SUM(hours)
            FROM entries
            WHERE project_id = Project.id
                AND createdby = $id
                AND deleted = 0
                AND YEAR(entry_date) = YEAR(NOW())
                AND WEEKOFYEAR(entry_date) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())) as Project__WeekHours,
        (SELECT SUM(hours)
            FROM entries
            WHERE project_id = Project.id
                AND deleted = 0) as Project__SpentHours,
        Project.budget_hours as TotalHours
    FROM projects as Project
        INNER JOIN users_projects UserProject on UserProject.project_id = Project.id
            AND UserProject.user_id = $id
        INNER JOIN customers Customer on Customer.id = Project.customer_id
    WHERE Project.deleted = 0
            AND Project.archived = 0
");
```